# PHP uksort fails to sort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of arrays that I want to sort by their keys, so I tried using uksort but the resulting array is not sorted at all... Not sure what I'm missing here. I'm using strcmp inside my custom sorter and it seems to produce the right results, but the final array is not sorted all the way through.

This is the relevant piece of code where I print out the array before and after sorting it:

```
echo "Before sort<br/>";
foreach($rowsByTemas as $r=>$row) {
    echo ("Name:".$r."<br/>");
}
echo "<br/>";

uksort($rowsByTemas, "myTemasSorter");

echo "<br/>After sort<br/>";
foreach($rowsByTemas as $r=>$row) {
    echo ("Name:".$r."<br/>");
}
```

And this is my custom sorter (I removed some elements which are not relevant for this example, in case you're wondering why I'm not using ksort):

```
function myTemasSorter($a, $b) {
    echo "comparing $a with $b<br/>";
    $result=strcmp($a, $b);
    echo "result: $result<br/>";
}
```

The result is this:

```
Before sort
Name:05 COMPETIDORES TAX ACCOUNTING
Name:04 COMPETIDORES LEGAL REGULATORY
Name:02 LEGAL REGULATORY
Name:01 CORPORATIVO
Name:03 TAX ACCOUNTING

comparing 02 LEGAL REGULATORY with 04 COMPETIDORES LEGAL REGULATORY
result: -512
comparing 03 TAX ACCOUNTING with 02 LEGAL REGULATORY
result: 256
comparing 02 LEGAL REGULATORY with 05 COMPETIDORES TAX ACCOUNTING
result: -768
comparing 01 CORPORATIVO with 02 LEGAL REGULATORY
result: -256
comparing 03 TAX ACCOUNTING with 01 CORPORATIVO
result: 512
comparing 04 COMPETIDORES LEGAL REGULATORY with 05 COMPETIDORES TAX ACCOUNTING
result: -256

After sort
Name:03 TAX ACCOUNTING
Name:01 CORPORATIVO
Name:02 LEGAL REGULATORY
Name:04 COMPETIDORES LEGAL REGULATORY
Name:05 COMPETIDORES TAX ACCOUNTING
```

When I run the same thing with ksort the results are correct, but then I can't include my custom sorting rules...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Holy crap, I just realized what I did wrong... I didn't return $result in the custom sorter function.

So it needs to be:

```
function myTemasSorter($a, $b) {
    echo "comparing $a with $b<br/>";
    $result=strcmp($a, $b);
    echo "result: $result<br/>";
    return $result;
}
```

That seems to fix the problem...

Comment: Congratulation, you just completed a session of [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) :-)

Comment: Also notice how your first result comes out reversed. This happens because  PHP 5.x incorrectly handles return value 0 (or undefined in your case). This is fixed in PHP7 ([more info](https://github.com/mblarsen/arrgh#php5-vs-php7))

Comment: So in PHP 5.x you should actually return 1 in cases where you would return 0.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) more carefully.

> **key_compare_func**
>
> The comparison function must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first argument is considered to be respectively less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Your comparison function doesn't return anything. The interpreter converts the returned result (nothing, i.e. `NULL`) to integer and gets zero. According to your comparison function, all the keys in the array are equal. The result of `uksort()` in this case depends on the way it is implemented (it the sorting is stable or not).